# Qt is not compiling for Windows Phone 8

Tags: qt, windows-phone-8, qmake

I recently downloaded Qt 5.4 for WinRT to develop apps for Windows Phone, but it isn’t compiling my code for WP8.
That’s the error from Compile Output:

> MAKEFILE_GENERATOR variable not set as a result of parsing : test.pro.
>   Possibly qmake was not able to find files included using "include(..)" - enable qmake debugging to investigate more. 20:45:53:
>   The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\winphone_x86\bin\qmake.exe" exited with
>   code 3. Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Qt 5.4.0 for
>   Windows Phone x86 MSVC2013 32bit (Emulator)) When executing step
>   "qmake"

I’ve installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, as well Windows Phone 8.0 SDK from VS2013 setup.

That’s de .pro file:

```
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

But it compiles without problems for Windows Runtime (Metro)
I’ve already searched, no answers.

Sorry for my terrible english anyway